# Clojure value equality and sets

Tags: clojure, set

If I have a custom type and I use it to create two separate instances having precisely the same values, what method could I use to determine that the two things are equivalent?  `identical?` and `=` and `==` don't seem to work.  I would have expected there to be some protocol for setting up type comparisons.  Ultimately, I would like it so that it would be impossible to add equivalent things to a set.

```
(deftype Ref [id])
(def r1 (->Ref 1))
(def r2 (->Ref 1))
(= r1 r2) ;false rather than true
(def refs #{})
(conj refs r1 r2) ;adds both, but want one
```

`=` works with `defrecord`, but how would I define `=` for `deftype`?

Comment: One small thing: `==` is only defined for numeric data `user> (== :a :a) => ClassCastException clojure.lang.Keyword cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.Numbers.equiv (Numbers.java:206)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`defrecord` already has this behavior you describe:

```
user=> (defrecord Point [x y])
user.Point
user=> (= (Point. 0 0) (Point. 0 0))
true
user=> (into #{} [(Point. 0 0) (Point. 1 1) (Point. 0 0)])
#{#user.Point{:x 1, :y 1} #user.Point{:x 0, :y 0}}
```

`deftype` on the other hand does not implement Clojure's usual structural equality by default (nor the readable print method that `defstruct` gives us):

```
user=> (deftype Pair [a b])
user.Pair
user=> (= (Pair. 0 0) (Pair. 0 0))
false
user=> (into #{} [(Pair. 0 0) (Pair. 1 1) (Pair. 0 0)])
#{#<Pair user.Pair@5de3182> #<Pair user.Pair@6497d63> #<Pair user.Pair@38eed810>}
```

That said, `deftype` is more powerful, and you can make it behave as we like:

```
user=> (deftype Tuple [a b]
         Object
         (equals [this other]
           (and (= (.a this) (.a other))
                (= (.b this) (.b other))))
         (toString [this]
           (str "<" (.a this) "," (.b this) ">"))
         (hashCode [this]
           (hash {:a (.a this) :b (.b this)}))
         Comparable
         (compareTo [this that]
           (compare [(.a this) (.b this)]
                    [(.a that) (.b that)])))
user.Tuple
user=> (= (Tuple. 0 0) (Tuple. 0 0))
true
user=> (into #{} [(Tuple. 0 0) (Tuple. 1 1) (Tuple. 0 0)])
#{#<Tuple <0,0>> #<Tuple <1,1>>}
```

Answer (score 7):

In your deftype, extend `Object` and implement `equals` to give them equality semantics:

```
(deftype Ref [id]
  Object
  (equals [_ other] (= id (.id other))))
```

Set containment will also require hashcode support:

```
(deftype Ref [id]
  Object
  (equals [_ other] (= id (.id other)))
  (hashCode [_] id) 
  clojure.lang.IHashEq 
  (hasheq [_] id))
```

I implemented both Java hash support and Clojure [hasheq](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Collections-Clojure%20collection%20hashes) support there. Implementing IHashEq will be faster.

Comment: for a `hash-set`, equals does not suffice (I tried it), `hashCode` is needed too.